# R: Generate a dummy vector for each category in data frame

Tags: r

I have a problem with R:

Lets assume a data frame called df with information on different individuals (e.g. age, gender) and a variable indicating the respective country.

Now, I would like to include for each individual as many rows as there are countries. Information on the different individuals (here: age, gender) should be the same for every added row for each individual. However, each row should hold one of the country names. In addition, a dummy variable should be included that takes on the value 1 if it is the row with the actual country and zero else.

In other words, we start with a data set with information on a individual and on its country. Afterwards, for each individual there is a row for each country and a dummy variable indicating which one is the "correct" country.+

If there are 5 Individuals and 5 countries: The original data set should contain 5 rows, the transformed one 25 (25*25).

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `dummyVars` function from `caret`. 
http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your dataframe is called `df` and your country variable `Country`. 
The following transforms your country variable into dummies:

```
df1 <- data.frame(df,model.matrix(~df$Country+0))
```

Then wouldn't it be sufficient to repeat each row of `df1` five times (or as many times as there are countries)?

```
df2 <- [rep(1:nrow(df1),length(unique(df$Country))),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the suggestions! Finally, I found an additional way to achieve this: Just add a variable (e.g. id) being 1 for all observations. Then use the command complete(data, variables to combine, fill=list(id=0)) from the package tidyr